# MySQL Query: query the PRODUCTS table (among others) and bring up BOTH the category AND subcategory

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wonder if someone could help me with a MySQL (v5.0.51) query I am having trouble with. I have a table like this:

```
category_id  | category_text  | subcategory
25           | Motor Controls | NULL
26           | Contactors     | 25
27           | Overloads      | 25
28           | Motors         | NULL
29           | Accessories    | 28
```

Each entry with *NULL* in the subcategory column represents a top-level category and the value in the *subcategory* tells which top-level category the subcategory belongs to.

For example above:
Contactors and Overloads belongs to Motor Control because their respective subcategory has a value of 25 which is the category_id (25) of Motor Controls

Now I use these values in a PRODUCTS table to store products but here I ONLY store the category_id of the subcategory.

```
product_id | product_item | product_supplier_id | product_description   | product_category_id
24         | Product A    | 39                  | Product A description | 27 --category_id of subcategory (ie.Overloads)
25         | Product B    | 39                  | Product B description | 26 --(Contactors)
```

The problem I am having is that I need **one** SQL query where I can query the PRODUCTS table (among others) and bring up BOTH the category AND subcategory. I can do it for one or the other but not both. I have tried UNION, JOINS etc but just cannot seem to get it. This is what I have so far which just brings up the subcategory.

```
SELECT p.*, c.company_name, pc.category_text AS subcategory 
FROM products p, company c, product_categories pc 
WHERE p.product_supplier_id = c.company_id 
AND p.product_category_id = pc.category_id
```

This results in the query generating the result below.

```
product_id | product_item | product_supplier_id | product_description   | product_category_id | company_name       | subcategory
24         | Product A    | 39                  | Product A description | 27                  | Product A Supplier | Overloads
25         | Product B    | 39                  | Product B description | 26                  | Product B Supplier | Contactors
```

Basically what I want is to add a column that contains the correct top-level category for each subcategory so it looks like this

```
24 | Product A | 39 | Product A description | 27 | Product A Supplier | **Motor Controls** | Overloads
```

Can I do this with the way the table is created or do I need to modify it?

Sorry I had some nice images to make it easier to understand but with a "reputation" of 1 , I couldn't post it.

Any help would be appreciated. Please note that I am using the query in PHP to access the MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  p.*, 
                c.company_name, 
                pc.category_text AS subcategory 
                ppc.category_text AS category 
  FROM  products p, 
                company c,
                product_categories pc,
                product_categories ppc
 WHERE  p.product_supplier_id = c.company_id 
   AND  p.product_category_id = pc.category_id
     AND    pc.subcategory = ppc.category_id
```

P.S: I wish MySQL had a better support for querying hierarchical data (like connect by clause in Oracle)

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. I guess I was making it more complicated than it needed to be...although everyone says that when presented with a solution right? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT  p.*, c.company_name, pc.category_text AS subcategory,ppc.category_text AS category 
  FROM  products p 
  left join company c on p.product_supplier_id = c.company_id
  left join product_categories pc on p.product_category_id = pc.category_id
  left join product_categories ppc on pc.subcategory = ppc.category_id
```

Comment: Just for the record this also worked. It gives me an alternative to learn from. Thanks!